# I am using Mat Autocomplete in angular's latest version using it normally in my project getting this type of error

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

```
    <form class="example-form">
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" for="id" >
    </mat-form-field>
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" id="id">

          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
            {{ option }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>

    </form>


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-auto',
  templateUrl: './auto.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./auto.component.css']
})
export class AutoComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  myControl: FormControl = new FormControl();

  options = [
    'One',
    'Two',
    'Three'
  ];

}
```

[image]

I am getting this error when i am using it in my project in which i used material design bootstrap .

Comment: Please post your error trace as text.

Comment: Use this reference: https://github.com/angular/angular-es/blob/master/public/docs/_examples/animations/ts/app/hero-list-auto.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You are using `id` but never declared it anywhere.

ts:

`public id = 'my-input';`